# Extension methods equivalents for CAR and CDR in .Net's Linq/IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I know you can say `SomeEnumerable.First()`. But there's no `.Rest`.

I know I could write one, but I am wondering if I am missing something.

Related Question:
[Are there ruby equivalents to car, cdr, and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522724/are-there-ruby-equivalents-to-car-cdr-and-cons)

Comment: Skip(1) does a pretty good job.

Comment: I was looking for what Skip() does and for some reason searched for "c# linq cdr" on a lark... and it worked!  That bit of LISP memory surfaced at the right moment :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [`CDR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR) you can use [`Enumerable.Skip(1)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

```
var cdrResultQuery = someIEnumerable.Skip(1);
```

Consider following example:

```
IEnumerable<int> someIEnumerable = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var cdrResultQuery = someIEnumerable.Skip(1);
foreach (var i in cdrResultQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

and you will get:

```
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I've even used that for other things, thanks. A little off this morning.